# watir-webdriver: how to select (and click) a javascript link?

Tags: javascript, android, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to write a test for a mobile webapp with cucumber+watir-webdriver, but one particular link on a splash message is giving me trouble.

The link I want to select is `<a class="btn" href="#">Close button</a>`, which is created on the page by javascript.

I tried these selectors:

```
browser.link :text => 'Close button'
browser.link(:class,"btn")
browser.div(:id,"vf_dialog_desc").link(:class,"btn") # with encompassing div
browser.div(:xpath,"//div[@id='vf_dialog_desc']/descendant::a[text()='Close button']")
```

However, all of them fail with a variant of the error:

```
Error: {"message":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (...snip xpath expression...) because of the following error:\nTypeError: Object #<an HTMLDocument> has no method 'evaluate'"}
```

Strangely enough, `browser.html.include?  'Close button'` is evaluating to true, so watir can access the element.

Note that, unlike other similar questions, this page is not in a frame.

The page structure is:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="home">
        <div id="vf_dialog_holder" class=" show">
            (...)
            <div id="vf_dialog_wrap">
                <h4 id="vf_dialog_head" style="display: block;" class=" vf_dialog_info_icon">Welcome to xpto</h4>
                <div id="vf_dialog_desc">
                    <img src="884857.jpg">
                    <p>Blurb.</p>
                    <a class="btn" href="#">Close button</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clr">
            </div>
         </div>
```

I am running watir-webdriver (0.6.4) on ruby-2.0.0-p247.

Answer (score 1):

Since the button is created via javascript, I am guessing that watir is trying to interact with the button before it becomes visible. Try explicitly waiting for the element.

If you just want to wait for the link to be present:

```
browser.link(:class => "btn").wait_until_present
```

If you want to do something with it (eg click it) once the link appears:

```
browser.link(:class => "btn").when_present.click
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but it's not an issue with visibility. `browser.html.include?` finds the "close button" text before even trying to fetch the element. Running `browser.link(:class => "btn").visible?` or the `wait_until_present` method will result in the same error as described.

Comment: `browser.html.include?` being true could be deceptive. It could mean that "close button" is in the content of a script and not yet an actual element.